# Storybook react-native both storybook in web and normal app on IOS

Tags: react-native, expo, storybook

I know I can use `storybook` and `react-native` guide to be able to use `storybook` in my app but the problem is I would like to have `storybook` that I can run in web and define all components there but also use expo to run my app on iOS emulator. How can I achieve that? So I can work on both at the same time:

- web for storybook and components for example on port 7007
- expo app that I run by `expo start` command and run iOS in emulator